# Is it possible to require or import resource from cdn in javascript or es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

using the svelte compiler to generate code from a synthetic file (a string). The output from this is also a string but it adds import statements from svelte itself. I need to remove all of these import statements from the generated code but I also need to take these import statements and add them in a way that I can import / require from a cdn.

I intend to parse out these import statements to something like:

```
import { SvelteComponent, append, etc. } from "svelte/internal";
```

and replace it with something like:

```
const { SvelteComponent, append, etc. } = svelte.internal;
```

My initial thought was if I could add the code inline to the js module to import / require the script (in this case, svelte) from a cdn in plain js / es6. The project is written in react and I have written my own hook for dynamically loading a script but I thought would need to add it to the iframe's window. But thinking back to how modules work, I believe adding the script to the parent window would also work. So my question is, how can I add the import for a script from a cdn into my javascript module?

Comment: Yes, it is possible: [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer depends on the host environment. For browsers, the answer is yes (assuming the resource you're importing is compatible with being imported). (In contrast, for Node.js the answer is no, at least at present.) Module specifiers in both of those environments can be full URLs. Beware that module scripts loaded via `import` are subject to the Same Origin Policy and so the other end must serve them with appropriate CORS headers to allow your site to use them. (CDNs typically do.)

Here's a browser example, importing the JavaScript module version of Vue.js:

```html
<script type="module">
import {version} from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.5/vue.esm-browser.js";
console.log(version);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks T.J. It is for an online code editor I am making so the environment would be browser. Do you have an example or link where I could fine more information?

Comment: @cbutler - Module specifiers for the web platform are defined by the HTML specification, [this section](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#fetch-a-module-script-tree) is probably the best place to look. [MDN's page on `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) is useful for general context.

Comment: Thanks again. To be clear, this snippet is written in the markup and not a javascript file correct? I think I need to edit my question as it's been closed. But I can clarify my use case and be more specific. I will update, I was just trying to avoid being overly complicated

Comment: @cbutler - The JavaScript panel of the Stack Snippets editor adds a `script` tag that doesn't have `type="module"`. But you can only use `import` in modules. That's why I've written the `script` tag explicitly in the HTML panel of the editor instead. But everything inside the script tag is JavaScript (modern, module JavaScriot).

Comment: Ahhh ok so I can just replace from "svelte/internal" with a full url? Too easy! Thanks T.J.! I will test it out. btw, The reason I need this is to be able to support svelte in a code editor I am making. check it out if you like :)  https://contrived-dev.herokuapp.com/